# How to remove this white line at the bottom of the progress bar

Tags: html, css

I created a progress bar in the CSS but after running there is a white line below the progress bar.

I have tried using `margin-bottom:0px` and `margin-bottom:-5px` in progress CSS but it doesn't work. is there any other way?
is this default from the progress bar?

```js
function progressbarOne() {
  var pointStart = "10";
  var pointEnd = "100";

  document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("value", pointStart);
  document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("max", pointEnd);
}

function progressbarTwo() {
  var pointStart = "10";
  var pointEnd = "100";

  document.getElementById("two").setAttribute("value", pointStart);
  document.getElementById("two").setAttribute("max", pointEnd);
}
```

```css
/*  Progress Bar  */
progress {
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #daa82b;
  white-space: pre;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.89) inset;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  white-space: pre;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.89) inset;
}
```

```html
<body onload="progressbarOne();progressbarTwo();">
  <div>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset style="height:175px; width:364px;background-color:#e9cb80">
        <label class="mb-0 blue-dark-text" style="font-size:15px;white-space: pre; "><b> Progress Bar</b></label>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="" class="mb-0" style="font-size:12px;color:black;white-space: pre;padding-left:8px"><b> One</b></label>
          <div id="referralBar" class="input-group border-bottom">
            <progress id="one" value="0" max="0"> </progress>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="" class="mb-0" style="font-size:12px;color:black;white-space: pre;padding-left:8px"><b> Two</b></label>
          <div id="cashbackBar" class="input-group border-bottom">
            <progress id="two" value="0" max="0"> </progress>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

This Image when i run in mobile  :

[image: Progress Bar]

Comment: The code works well. No white lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the "border-bottom" class from the referralBar&cashbackBar div the border is gone. It is there because you are using bootstrap, see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/